# How to extract rar file without "Extracting ~" message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rar

When I use zip command in shell script, I set on -q (--quiet) option.
Is there the option for rar command?

I don't want to show "Extracting ~" message and rar version infomartion in console.

I installed rar command by `sudo apt-get install rar`.
And the version is
"RAR 4.00 beta 3   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   17 Dec 2010"

I'm extracting file by using `rar e $rarfile`.

Comment: What software are you using to extract it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the basic information. Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your tags to include the distro you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always just pipe `stdout` into /dev/null.

```
rar e <rarfile> > /dev/null
```

This shouldn't stop it from printing error messages to the console though.

Answer (score 8):

Use the switch.

```
-id[c,d,p,q]
      Disable messages. c-copyright, d-'done' message, p-percentage, q-be completely quiet
```

For example, for absolutely no output:

```
rar e <rarfile> -idq
```

P.S. -inul has the same function as -idq

Comment: `-inul` also silent error messages if any, while `-idq` does not.